# auctex preview at point shows equations for the entire document

Tags: spacemacs, auctex, preview-latex

I am using the latex-layer (auctex) in spacemacs. When I use `preview-at-point` it renders all of the equations in the document. Is there a way to really make it render on the equation at the cursor?

Also the `preview-clearout` works in a weird way. It toggles the images back to text but only for the equations which are before the cursor (not including the one under the cursor). On the other hand `preview-clearout-buffer` works fine.

Comment: Starting at point it searches in both directions until it hits a document boundary or it finds some up-to-date preview-image. There it puts the bounds for the region to be re-rendered. If all formulae are rendered and one introduces some local changes then preview only renders a few formulae around point with `preview-at-point`.

Comment: @Tobias I did not clearly understand your comment. Are you saying that this is the proper behavior of `preview-at-point`?

Comment: Yes, it is the proper behavior. `preview-at-point` renders all the formulae in the full buffer only at the first time. Afterwards only those formulae around point are rendered that needs re-rendering.